# Install latest version of Nginx on Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I can see that the latest mainline version of nginx is 1.23.4

http://nginx.org/en/download.html

My Ubuntu server is running nginx version: nginx/1.22.1

I have tried these commands but it still updates to 1.22.1.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove nginx
sudo apt install nginx
```

Is version 1.23.4 not available for Ubuntu ?

Comment: What's wrong with the [official installation instructions](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/#official-debian-ubuntu-packages)? It contains packages up to 1.24.

Comment: Generally (enterprise) Linux distributions like Ubuntu ship with a specific version and will backport security fixes (when necessary) and remain on that version for the life time of that (major) Ubuntu release. As long as you regularly apply (security)  updates on your still supported Ubuntu (LTS) release you won't need to upgrade to the latest upstream version to remain secure and/or fix known bugs.